# Vue shallowRef mutating value does not trigger update

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have set up a small program to test shallowRef.

```
The manual
/*
const state = shallowRef({ count: 1 })
// does NOT trigger change
state.value.count = 2
// does trigger change
state.value = { count: 2 }
*/

<script setup>
import { shallowRef } from 'vue';

let value = 0;
const shallowState = shallowRef({count: value});
</script>
```

The manual says that the first should update. But only the second updates. Why?

```
<template>
  <button @click="shallowState.value = {count: ++value}">shallowRef {{ shallowState.count }}</button>
  <br><br>
  <button @click="shallowState = {count: ++value}">shallowRef {{ shallowState.count }}</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect to use `.value` in template code because the ref has already been unwrapped, therefore `shallowState.value` is undefined.  In effect you're trying to assign `shallowState.value.value`.

It's made more evident by the second button example.  `shallowState = ...` where shallowState is `const` which makes it's not reassignable.  The reason it works is because it's not actually reassigning `shallowState` but is reassigning `shallowState.value`.

This automatic unwrapping is done as a convenience.  If you don't prefer it you can substitute the inline handler with a function defined in your script code where you are required to use `.value` when reassigning ref values.

Comment: Ok. moving the  shallowState.value = {count: ++value} into a function and calling it did it.